# Issue when using libcurl to call REST API

Tags: libcurl

We are developing application using C to call some REST API.
We have the following error:

```
0x0900000006567214  ssl3_new() + 0x34
0x090000000658abb8  tls1_new() + 0x18
0x09000000150f7f50  SSL_CTX_check_private_key() + 0x68
0x0900000014d6831c  ossl_connect_step1(??, ??) + 0xaec
0x0900000014d696a4  ossl_connect_common(??, ??, ??, ??) + 0x184
0x0900000014d60858  Curl_ssl_connect_nonblocking(??, ??, ??) + 0x9c
0x0900000014d773bc  https_connecting(??, ??) + 0x20
0x0900000014d79214  Curl_http_connect(??, ??) + 0x168
0x0900000014d71738  multi_runsingle(??, ??, ??) + 0x608
0x0900000014d72cf4  curl_multi_perform(??, ??) + 0xf4
0x0900000014d5e0f8  curl_easy_perform(??) + 0x158
```

The version of OpenSSL is:
#: openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019

CURL version:

#: curl --version
curl 7.73.0 (powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.9.0) libcurl/7.73.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2t libssh2/1.9.0
Release-Date: 2020-10-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets

We suspect that there is an issue with version of SSL protocol that should be used. Please let us know if you have faced such errors.

Comment: This is a call stack, not an error.

Comment: Yes this is a call stack. Actually the program we made using CURL crash and print this call stack.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: The call stack you see was the result of using DBX command.